# Angular6 - Child route with Empty Path not loaded

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I am converting my Angular 4 application to Angular 6. However, I am facing issues while making the routing related changes.

Now when I run my application, Home component is loaded but the child component `ContentsComponent` which has empty path is not loaded.

Routing in my application is defined like below:

**app.routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'support', component: SupportComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**home.routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, 
    children: [
      { path: '', component: ContentsComponent }, //<-- This component is not loaded
      { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class HomeRoutingModule { }
```

**home.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
      HomeRoutingModule
      ],
  exports: [],
  declarations: [ HomeComponent, ContentsComponent ],
  providers: [],
})

export class HomeModule { }
```

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HomeModule
  ],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  providers: [
    { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy }
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**home.component.html**

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**EDIT:** Please note that I don't want to display anything after the `/home` url part.

Comment: Your code works fine in https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tggwpc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhome%2Fhome.component.html

Answer (score 0):

For routing in children component you need to mention its name.

Replace '/home' by just 'home'.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'support', component: SupportComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

And in HomeRoutingModule you don't need to mention 'home' again.

Just name children components only as below.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', component: HomeComponent, 
    children: [
      { path: 'content', component: ContentsComponent },
      { path: '**', redirectTo: 'content' }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class HomeRoutingModule { }
```

And **If you don't want to change routing path while routing**, then there are two options

```
this.router.navigate(['/home/content'], { skipLocationChange: true });
```

or

```
const routes: Routes = [
      {
        path: '', component: HomeComponent, 
        children: [
          { path: '', redirectTo: 'content' }
          { path: 'content', component: ContentsComponent },
          { path: '**', redirectTo: 'content' }
        ]
      }
    ];
```

Ask me if any query.
Thanks.

Comment: Please see my edit to the question. I don't want to name the `ContentsComponent` route.

Comment: If you don't want to affect url with navigation, then you will have to use 'skipLocationChange: true'. Have a look at https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras

Answer (score 0):

Its because of relative path. Try below should work.

```
children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: '/home/content' }, 
      { path: 'content ', component: ContentsComponent }, 
      { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }
    ]
```

Comment: That works but I don't want to display anything after the `/home` url part.